# API-Platform Richardson Maturity Model level 3

Tags: rest, api-platform.com, symfony5

I need to develop a simple REST API which respects Richardson Maturity Model level 3 so with some links to other routes.
To do this work, I use API-Platform.

In this API, I can get a list of users, get one user, and post / delete / patch a user.

In the Reponse body when I get one user I have the URI `"@id": "/api/users/87"`, so that's good.

**But I wonder if it's not enough to respect level 3, and could for example also includes links to delete or patch the user ?**

I tried to install `willdurand/hateoas-bundle` and to add theses links following the doc but it does not have any effect on my response body. I have the format `application/hal+json` enabled in my API-Platform config.

When I try to delete all formats in `api_plateform.yaml` excepts hal+json, I got a `406 Error: Not Acceptable`.

Allow me to create this new thread because I searched a lot and found nothing which could help me with Richardson Maturity Model level 3 specificly to API-Platform.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't like the maturity model at all as it gives a false impression of what REST services/clients really need. I.e. even at level 3 you don't have everything you need to really adhere to all of the constraints imposed by the REST architecture. I.e. the MM-L3 doesn't talk about media-types at all, which is one of the key aspects of the REST architecture in order to decouple clients from particular services.

Comment: @RomanVottner Thank your for your answer ! So I'll also look at media-types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact,  links to delete or patch the user are same as link to get the user, it's juste the method which changes, so they are well present in the doc and Richardson level 3 is well respected.

So it is a non-sense to want to use a Bundle to do that, since it's natively implemented.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.